# How to modify file to get Bibtex to work

Tags: bibtex, formatting, templates, thesis

I am using this template, downloaded from here http://maths.dur.ac.uk/Thesis/

I know I shouldn't be using a template, but I am so far through now I really dont want to have to reformat everything.

So if you go on that site, it lists which files are downloaded, and in the file `ref.tex` the description says that if you want to use Bibtex you need to modify this file. How would I go about modifying this file?

Notice that there are no `.blg`, `.bbl` or `.bst` files which is a worry as they're required for Bibtex.

Hope this question is clear, I will try to explain more if need to

Edit: Direct download link https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/durham-university-thesis

Edit: Screenshot of what the folder looks like https://gyazo.com/765933d04c9aad4233e80ec84f22bb0c

Screenshot of what the `ref.tex` file looks like https://gyazo.com/1fb407cb8187bbb4081b00a29a12622e

Comment: Added it to the docuemnt

Comment: All your previous questions received answers, but you only accepted a single one :(

Comment: My bad Sam, I have accepted all the ones that worked for me. I'll try to make sure I accept them in the future!

Comment: Hi, why did you delte your MWE?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are going to use bibtex, modify `ref.tex` so that it contains (probably only) a suitable `\bibliographystyle` command and a `\bibliography` command which refers to your own `.bib` file. If in doubt as proof of concept just choose `\bibliographystyle{plain}` for testing purposes.

You won't expect to have `.blg` or `.bbl` files provided with the template: those are generated when you run `bibtex` which by definition you haven't. You could have a `.bst` file, but since the template seems to assume (amazingly!) that you will do your bibliography by hand, it doesn't have such a file. So you are free to select one to format the bibliography in the style you favour or are required to use.

Obviously you will need to have a suitable `.bib` database file and have included some citations in the text -- and then run bibtex, which it sounds like you aren't doing yet (because if you were you'd have a log, if only one containing errors and warnings!).

#### Updated

I managed to download the files from your attached link. The following works for me:

- Add `\usepackage{apacite}` in `format.tex`
- Amend `thesis.tex` so that it was only including one chapter and the reference section (this just to enable me to have a workable document).
- Write a file `mybib.bib` including a suitable test entry of type `@book` called `tst`.
- Delete the boilerplate from chapter 1, so that it only includes a citation to `tst`.
- Replace `ref.tex` with `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and `\bibliography{mybib}`
- Compile with LaTex
- Compile with bibTeX
- Compile again with LaTeX

If this is not working, you need to (1) confirm that you have run LaTeX and bibTeX and LaTeX again; (2) make sure that you have bib entries for all the citations in the chapters (if you are just using existing boilerplate chapters, you won't unless you've defined them). If it's not getting references it's failing at some point and looking at the logs should tell you where.

Comment: Hi, thanks to the reply. Your first sentence says there's no download link, so I've just added one. Hope this will help you with the answer

Comment: I just read your reply, and what you said sounds very similar to what I did do. So in my `ref.tex` file i replaced everything in there with just a `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and just the name of my `.bib` file. See I don't have a `.bst` file. I @m going to attach 2 screenshots, the first will be what my thesis folder looks like, the second is the `ref.tex` file. I'll add this in an edit of the original question

Comment: Well, this works for me. If you want to use apacite, you need to load the package too, I think, by adding it to `format.tex`. By doing that, and by including a cite command in a chapter, with a suitable `.bib`, it compiled as expected.

Comment: Still not working, says the citation is undefined and there are undefined references. but I have done exactly what you said to do

Comment: How long should it take to compile. I think the problem is when Im compiling, I must be doing it wrong

Comment: When I try to run this it just says. `No file ref.bbl.` but I didn't think I needed this file?

Comment: If it's short, it really should compile pretty quickly. The LaTeX compilation might take a second or two. The bibtex run should terminate almost instantly. It should produce a file "thesis.bbl". Are you sure you are running LaTeX (and bibTeX) on the **main** file: you `latex thesis` and `bibtex thesis` not `refs`: those get `included`.